# Nginx - Address already in use

Tags: nginx

If I run: `service nginx restart` I have this error:

```
root@user /etc/nginx/sites-enabled # service nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
nginx.
```

How to fix it? I have also apache conf running on port 80.

Comment: why do you need two different servers? Assuming you do, don't use the same port for both.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind both Apache and Nginx on the same port 80/tcp.

Comment: How to change nginx to another port?

Comment: Change the directive `listen 80` in your server/virtualhost section

Comment: `nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` and I added `listen 44444` but sill is `80` (the same error like in question)

Comment: What else can I do?

Comment: Be sure there are no `listen` directives duplicates, then restart Nginx.

Comment: I'm sure. Only listen 44444;

Comment: Did you restart nginx then?

Comment: Yes, `service nginx restart`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run two applications listening on same port, in this instance on port 80. You can either change the port for apache or for nginx

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following

```
server {
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080;
```

P.S. it is good practice to use nginx like a frontend and apache like a backend.

Comment: Or apache to serve static file + nginx to serve server-side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to check how many services run on port 80. To check that, you could run the following command:

```
sudo netstat -plant | grep 80
```

This would show you which service exactly is listening on port 80 and then you can make a decision whether you want to have that service as is or have Nginx instead.

If it is Apache, you will need to decide whether you want to use Apache or Nginx.

If you only want to have Nginx, you need to stop Apache first:

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2 && sudo systemctl start nginx
```